# Troubleshooting 'distribution not found' pkg_resources with Poetry

Tags: python, python-poetry

I am building a cli application, in which I am using [poetry](https://python-poetry.org/) and `pyproject.toml` to define my application's version:

```
[tool.poetry]
name = "fili"
version = "0.1.0"
description = "My super awesome program."
authors = ["Jacob Pavlock <jtpavlock@gmail.com>"]
license = "MIT"
```

Now, I'd like to programatically access this version number in the CLI for my application, so I added the following code to `cli.py`

```py
import argparse
import pkg_resources


def main():
    """Run our cli."""
    VERSION = pkg_resources.get_distribution("fili").version

    fili_parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description="Run fili.")
    fili_parser.add_argument(
        "--version", action="version", version="%(prog)s {0}".format(VERSION)
    )


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

However, when run, I get the following error:

```
$ ./fili/cli.py 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./fili/cli.py", line 22, in <module>
    main()
  File "./fili/cli.py", line 11, in main
    VERSION = pkg_resources.get_distribution("fili").version
  File "/home/jacob/.cache/pypoetry/virtualenvs/fili-yAte7WxV-py3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 481, in get_distribution
    dist = get_provider(dist)
  File "/home/jacob/.cache/pypoetry/virtualenvs/fili-yAte7WxV-py3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 357, in get_provider
    return working_set.find(moduleOrReq) or require(str(moduleOrReq))[0]
  File "/home/jacob/.cache/pypoetry/virtualenvs/fili-yAte7WxV-py3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 900, in require
    needed = self.resolve(parse_requirements(requirements))
  File "/home/jacob/.cache/pypoetry/virtualenvs/fili-yAte7WxV-py3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 786, in resolve
    raise DistributionNotFound(req, requirers)
pkg_resources.DistributionNotFound: The 'fili' distribution was not found and is required by the application
```

For reference, my project directory structure

```
$ tree
.
├── fili
│   ├── cli.py
│   ├── __init__.py
│   └── __pycache__
│       ├── cli.cpython-38.pyc
│       └── __init__.cpython-38.pyc
├── fili.egg-info
│   ├── dependency_links.txt
│   ├── PKG-INFO
│   ├── SOURCES.txt
│   └── top_level.txt
├── LICENSE
├── poetry.lock
├── pyproject.toml
└── README.md
```

I have installed my package with `poetry install`, but what else am I missing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to make sure that the environment that `poetry` installed it into when you ran `poetry install` is also the one that is executed when you run `./fili/cli.py`. The latter command will just grab whatever is registered as the system's `python` binary to run your script, while `poetry install` will try to install it into whichever virtual environment is activated - or create a new one if none is.

To solve this issue, you can 1) run `poetry shell` in order to activate the virtual environment that `poetry` used, after which a call like `fili/cli.py` will use the activated `python`, or you 2) delegate the call explicitly with `poetry run fili/cli.py` instead.

---

If this didn't solve the problem, there are two other issues that might be the cause. The first is that you're using `pkg_resources` with python3.8. You shouldn't do that, the standard library was extended with [`importlib.metadata.version`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/importlib.metadata.html#distribution-versions), which is just a straight upgrade.

And finally, running part of an installed package as a script (read, directly executing a .py file instead of, say, a module: `python -m fili`) is a bit unsafe. It might mess up imports in confusing ways, which is usually solved by defining [entrypoints for scripts](https://python-poetry.org/docs/pyproject/#scripts).

Comment: The reason I am using `pkg_resources` is because I'd like my program to support python3.6 as well. Also, I have since moved on to using a script entrypoint, but I appreciate the comments. This was indeed the answer, I meant to come back to this once I discovered the solution. You can also prepend the command with `poetry run` to fix this issue.

Comment: good point bout `poetry run`, I'll add it to the post. regarding backwards compatibility, the core lib guys release an official [backport for `importlib.metadata`](https://pypi.org/project/importlib-metadata/) on pypi that you can install in python <3.8, but I can see why you might want to avoid that. Good thing you solved your issue =)